# How do I change the menu they remain united?

Tags: html, css

I have [this](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/) page

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="content-menu">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="logo-mobile">
                <a href="#"> <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/logo-mobile.png"></a>
                <ul class="lang-top navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">En</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">fr</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
            <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
                <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22"><a title="Home" href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=4">Home</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a title="News" href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=10">News</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-65" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-65"><a title="Events" href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=63">Events</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-71"><a title="Delivery" target="_blank" href="http://www.smood.ch/en/156_bagel-house-café">Delivery</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-23"><a title="About us" href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=6">About us</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a title="Contact" href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=12">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <ul class="lang-top navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/logo-menu.png">
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png">
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="#">MENU</a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="#">En</a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="#">fr</a>
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png">
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png">
                </li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/menu.png">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately when I press `ctrl` and `minus` a problem occurs ... a distance that does not know where it came from.

[image]

Where do you think it comes from and how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you increase the screen size its the right menu thats altering as it has a css `float: right;`on it.

So the left menu will always be there while the right will always float right, so on larger screens hence the GAP

Its located on the :

```
  .navbar-right {  float: right....
```

Also

```
 @media (min-width: 768px)
  .navbar-right {
      float: right !important;
```

If you remove the floats it will join up, but its what you want etc.  Use the chrome dev to try it out on that link

Answer (score 0):

IMO there is something wrong in your code, for example you put  `<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav navbar-nav">` inside a div that uses 100% of the space and it's not clearfixed so it's height is 0px. 
When you zoom out it's like to see the site on a wider screen, so the navigation menu's behavior is right, because one is floated left and the other floated right, you should try to put all navigation links and logo inside a container centered on the page, so zooming out they will stay always on the center.